# Google Big Query, UPDATE, when matching the first row

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-update

I have this query

```
UPDATE `TABLE 1` A
SET A.zip_code=B.postalCode
FROM `TABLE 2` B
WHERE (A.business_identifier = B.namespace AND B.postalCode is not null)
```

I'm gettin this error
ERROR:

```
UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row
```

Because in Table 2 for namespace I have duplicate values:
Can I add something to the query so it can get the postalCode from the first namespace that matches ?

UPDATE : I USED THIS CODE AND IT WORKED

```
UPDATE `Table1` A
SET A.zip_code=B.postalCode
FROM (
   select ID, postalCode
    from (
    select *,
          row_number() over (partition by ID order by postalCode) as row_number
    from `TABLE 2`
    ) as row
    where (row_number = 1 AND postalCode is not null)
    ) B
WHERE (A.ID = B.ID AND B.postalCode is not null);
```

Comment: Thanks, I got my answer in your question only.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a sub-select in your FROM like below:

```
UPDATE so_test.table_1 A
SET A.zip_code=B.postalCode
FROM (
    select postalcode, namespace  
    from so_test.table_2
    where postalcode is not null
    qualify rank() OVER (partition by namespace order by postalcode) =1
) B
WHERE (A.business_identifier = B.namespace AND B.postalCode is not null);
```

You may need/want to change how you define the 'first' record by modifying the `RANK` conditions.

This successfully updates with the following sample data

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE so_test.table_1
AS
SELECT 1 as zip_code, 'a' as business_identifier UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as zip_code, 'b' as business_identifier UNION ALL
SELECT 3 as zip_code, 'c' as business_identifier 
;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE so_test.table_2
AS
SELECT 1 as postalcode, 'a' as namespace UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 as postalcode, 'a' as namespace
;
```